# Generic cluster of docker containers on marathon

Tags: ssh, docker, mesos, marathon

I am deploying a number of docker containers as marathons apps. Each container should be able to communicate with everyone else using SSH. How do I set hosts and ssh keys for the deployed containers, so that they can communicate with each other without username and password.

Also, trying to understand scenario, when the new container is added as a result of scaling, so the rest of the cluster should became aware of a new node, and vice versa.

Comment: Does each container need to have it's own keys or maybe they can share keys withing node they are running on?

Comment: They can share, but I still can't image in what sequence this has to be arranged. Something like: after deployment pull the SSH key from a known location?